# Mediawiki file upload final steps fail

Tags: php, iis-7, mediawiki

I have a mediawiki set up on an IIS7 server. It was set up as described in the manual. I activated file upload as described [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuring_file_uploads). I think I've got the folder permissions right: modify-read-write for the `IIS_IUSRS` group on the `images` subdir of the mediawiki install. My `php.ini` also allows file uploads.

When I try to upload a png image, I can see a temporary file with a name of `phpF267.tmp` being created in a temp folder that is obviously a png file (magic header). However, Mediawiki tells me that it was unable to open the lock file for `mwstore://local-backend/local-public/f/f1/bla.png` and does not copy the file. It does not even create the directories `f/f1` in the `images` folder.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can fix this by
Turning off these settings in LocalSettings.php

## $wgUseImageMagick = true;

## $wgImageMagickConvertCommand = "/usr/bin/convert";